# Pegar Inputs com type="money"

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskmoney

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name*='pvn'").maskMoney({
        thousands : '.',
        decimal : ','
    });
})
```

---

Faço isso para pegar os inputs com `name='pvn'` e aplicar uma máscara, mas gostaria de aplicar essa máscara a todos os campos do tipo money, pois assim não preciso fazer uma função para cada input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar o selector: `[type=money]`

```js
$(function() {
  $('[type=money]').maskMoney({
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ','
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<label for="valor1">Valor 1</label>
<input type="money" id="valor1" />|
<label for="valor2">Valor 2:</label>
<input type="money" id="valor2" />
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem! Obrigado!!